# Can I grow a bay tree (Laurus nobilis) indoors?

Tags: indoors

I want to grow a bay tree for cooking purposes. Since it is not frost resistant I have to at least partially put the plant inside. Are lighting conditions without additional artificial light sufficient? Is there anything else to consider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can grow a bay tree indoors. It will need the sunniest spot available and plenty of fresh air (it doesn't mind draughts) so near a slightly open window would be good, and should be watered sparingly in winter, when it's easy to overwater as its growth naturally slows with changing light levels. Best kept trimmed as a shrub 3-4 feet high max, and placed outdoors in summer. When indoors, mist leaves regularly, keep in a cool position away from heat sources, but preferably good daylight and with some sun, repot as necessary in spring. When moving it outdoors, harden it off first, and expect some 'transition shock' symptoms when you have to move it back indoors again.